# Crear una matriz 3x3 con valores (i,j)

Tags: matrices

Quiero crear una matriz 3x3 con los valores `i` y `j`, donde `i` es el índice de fila y `j` el de columna. Solo he sido capaz de sacar esto:

```
nrow = 3
ncol= 3
matriz = [["0" for j in range(ncol)]for i in range(nrow)]
```

El resultado debería darme esto:

```
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Empieza especificando con etiquetas a que lenguaje se refiere tu pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ejercicio ya lo tienes practicamente completo, si lo comprendi bien, lo unico que debes hacer cambiar el "0" por (j,i)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si hago eso me sale : [[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2]] pero no [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]

Comment: El codigo lo probe en python 3.8.10, si estas programando en otro lenguaje por favor especificarlo